# how do i round to 3 decimal places

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

My code shows 3 decimal places but in the 3rd decimal place its always a 0. What can I do to fix this to where it gives me the third number.

```
print ('Radius     Area     Circumference')

for Radius in range(1 , 11):

    Area = (Radius)**2*3.14
    Circumference =  (Radius)*2*(3.14)
    a = Radius
    b = Area
    c = Circumference



    print ('{:2d}    {:10.3f}   {:10.3f}'.format(a, (b), (c)))
```

here is an example of how its reading out.

```
Radius     Area     Circumference
 1         3.140        6.280
 2        12.560       12.560
 3        28.260       18.840
 4        50.240       25.120
```

Comment: The issue is that you only have `pi` to two decimal places. change it to be more precise 3.14159 for example. Better yet it to use the constant defined in module math (math.pi).

Comment: `import math` and use `math.pi`

Comment: btw, you don't need to put the names into parentheses, no need to do `(x)`, use just `x` instead.

Comment: it was using 3.14 instead of math.pi   you should put that in a answer so I can give you credit for it

Answer (score 2):

```
import math

print ('Radius     Area     Circumference')

for radius in range(1 , 11):
    area = radius**2*math.pi
    circumference =  radius*2*math.pi
    print('{:2d}    {:10.3f}   {:10.3f}'.format(radius, area, circumference))
```